# jQuery closest method is not working for class

Tags: jquery, laravel

I am trying to get the id of an item from a list I have fetched in a table. Whenever I am trying to get the id using the closest method, it does not work.

```js
$(".remove-from-cart").click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var package_id = $("#package_id").closest('.p_id').val();
  console.log(package_id);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
<tr class="package_id">
  <td class="cart_product_img d-flex align-items-center">
    <a href="#"><img src="img/product-img/product-9.jpg" alt="Package"></a>
    <h6>{{ $details['course_title'] }}</h6>
  </td>
  <input type="hidden" class="p_id" value="{{ $details['package_type_id'] }}">
  <td class="price">$<span id="price_per_head">{{ $details['price_per_head'] }}</span></td>
  <td class="qty">
    <div class="quantity">
      <span class="qty-minus" id="qty-minus" onclick="var effect = document.getElementById('qty'); var qty = effect.value; if( !isNaN( qty ) &amp;&amp; qty &gt; 1 ) effect.value--;return false;">
        <i class="fa fa-minus" aria-hidden="true"></i>
      </span>
      <input type="number" class="qty-text" id="qty" step="1" min="1" max="99" name="member_number" value="{{$details['number_of_members']}}">
      <span class="qty-plus" id="qty-plus" onclick="var effect = document.getElementById('qty'); var qty = effect.value; if( !isNaN( qty )) effect.value++;return false;">
        <i class="fa fa-plus" aria-hidden="true"></i>
       </span>
    </div>
  </td>
  <td class="total_price">
    $
    <span id="total">{{ $details['price'] }} </span>
  </td>
  <td class="actions" data-th="">
    <button class="btn btn-danger btn-sm remove-from-cart">
      <i class="fa fa-trash-o"></i>
    </button>
  </td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Please take care to format your code so it's readable. I've done this for you and added it to a snippet so it can be executed. As an aside, I'd strongly suggest you change your code so you don't use `onX` attributes in your HTML, and if you absolutely must use them, reference functions instead of writing that much JS inline in the HTML

Comment: Thanks for updating my code and your suggestion

Comment: `.closest()` works UP the DOM tree, so it would work if it was `<element class="p_id"><element id="package_id">...</element></element>`. If you want to search DOWN the DOM tree, you need to use `.find()`, which would work for your case of `<element id="package_id"><element class="p_id">...</element></element>`. Check the docs for `.closest()` and `.find()`: https://api.jquery.com/closest/ and https://api.jquery.com/find/.

Answer (score 0):

have a look at the line

```
var package_id = $("#package_id").closest('.p_id').val();
```

the package_id is a class name you should replace above line with

```
var package_id = $(".package_id").closest('.p_id').val();
```

Comment: I mistakenly kept this, I actually tried it as class name as well

Comment: p_id class is not the closest element rather it's a child element of package_id, 
use *children* instead of *closest*.

Comment: I get the first items id ech time I click on buttons (for other items) in case of children/find

Answer (score 0):

closest() function will not work here

You should use find() method instead

```
$(".remove-from-cart").click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();       
    var package_id = $("#package_id").find('.p_id').val();
    console.log(package_id);
});
```

Or If you have class name than just with class name

```
var package_id = $(".package_id").find('.p_id').val();
```

Answer (score 0):

if button is in , use onclick button for get package_id :

```
<button class="btn btn-danger btn-sm remove-from-cart" onclick="remove({{ $details['package_type_id'] }})">
      <i class="fa fa-trash-o"></i>
</button>

function remove(package_id){ 
alert(package_id);
}
```